# Weird error when testing app on my iPhone device?

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling

I am just testing my app after some updates.. It works fine in the simulator but when I am testing it on my own device it is giving me this error:

[image]

What does it mean and how can I get it away?

Comment: Close  xcode, and reopen it.

Comment: It's still there @Rroobb

Comment: Have you cleaned your project? Product Tab and select clean.

Comment: That of course did it.. Stupid error but thank you @Rroobb!

Comment: i have clean project and reopen xcode but not solve this error